# Тесты Junit для калькулятора

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, верно ли сделал проверку Junit  тестами?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame {
    private String[] operation = {"+"};
    private double first_value = 0;
    private double second_value = 0;

    JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Калькулятор"); //форма
    //Создание панели для кнопок грид лояут(Менеджер расположения)
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 5, 5));
    JPanel batton_equally = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(1, 1));
    //Создаем панель для текста
    JPanel panel_text = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    //Создаем текстовое поле
    JTextField jtextfield = new JTextField(20);

    //Создаем кнопки
    JButton bt1 = new JButton("7");
    JButton bt2 = new JButton("8");
    JButton bt3 = new JButton("9");
    JButton btС = new JButton("С");
    JButton bt4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton bt5 = new JButton("5");
    JButton bt6 = new JButton("6");
    JButton bt_div = new JButton("/");
    JButton bt7 = new JButton("1");
    JButton bt8 = new JButton("2");
    JButton bt9 = new JButton("3");
    JButton bt_mult = new JButton("*");
    JButton bt10 = new JButton(".");
    JButton bt11 = new JButton("0");
    JButton bt_res = new JButton("=");
    JButton bt13 = new JButton("+");
    JButton bt14 = new JButton("-");

    public Calculator() {

        jframe.setSize(300, 300);
        //Обработка щелчка на системной кнопке закрытия окна
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  //?
        jframe.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //Выравнивание текста в поле по правому краю
        jtextfield.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        //Установка шрифта и размер текстового поля
        jtextfield.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        //Задаем вид и размер шрифта кнопок
        btС.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        bt_div.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        bt_mult.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        bt10.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        bt_res.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        bt13.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        bt14.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        //Добавление кнопки на панель
        panel.add(bt1);
        panel.add(bt2);
        panel.add(bt3);
        panel.add(btС);
        panel.add(bt4);
        panel.add(bt5);
        panel.add(bt6);
        panel.add(bt_div);
        panel.add(bt7);
        panel.add(bt8);
        panel.add(bt9);
        panel.add(bt_mult);
        panel.add(bt10);
        panel.add(bt11);
        panel.add(bt13);
        panel.add(bt14);
        batton_equally.add(bt_res);
        //цвет панели
        panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        //Добавляем текстовое поле на панель
        panel_text.add(jtextfield, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //Добавляем панель текста на форму
        jframe.add(panel_text, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //Добавляем панель кнопок на форму
        jframe.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jframe.add(batton_equally, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //Видимость формы
        jframe.setVisible(true);

        //Обработчики события "Нажатие на кнопку"
        //ActionListener - слушатель
        bt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtextfield.setText(jtextfield.getText() + "7");
            }
        });
        bt2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtextfield.setText(jtextfield.getText() + "8");
            }
        });
        bt3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtextfield.setText(jtextfield.getText() + "9");
            }
        });
        bt4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtextfield.setText(jtextfield.getText() + "4");
            }
        });
        bt5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtextfield.setText(jtextfield.getText() + "5");
            }
        });
        bt6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtextfield.setText(jtextfield.getText() + "6");
            }
        });
        bt7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtextfield.setText(jtextfield.getText() + "1");
            }
        });
        bt8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtextfield.setText(jtextfield.getText() + "2");
                jtextfield.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        bt9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtextfield.setText(jtextfield.getText() + "3");
            }
        });
        //Запрещаем ввод точки более 1 раза
        //Анонимный обработчик нажатия actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        //Выводим на экран точку потом проверяем эту точу в регулярном выражении и если верно то выводим точку
        bt10.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String newText = jtextfield.getText() + ".";
                if (validinput(newText)) {
                    jtextfield.setText(newText);
                }
            }
        });
        bt11.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtextfield.setText(jtextfield.getText() + "0");
            }
        });
        //При нажатии на "C" удаляем последнюю цифру
        btС.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String temp = jtextfield.getText();
                //обрабатываем исключение, чтобы не было возможности стереть пустое значение
                try {
                    jtextfield.setText(temp.substring(0, temp.length() - 1));
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                }
            }
        });

//        Работаем с кнопками операции
//        Для каждого арифметического действия запомнить его, сохранить текущее число в переменной first_value и
//        сбрасывать число для ввода нового
        bt14.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    first_value = Double.valueOf(jtextfield.getText());
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                }
                jtextfield.setText("");
                operation[0] = "-";
            }
        });
        bt_div.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    first_value = Double.valueOf(jtextfield.getText());
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                }
                jtextfield.setText("");
                operation[0] = "/";
            }
        });
        bt_mult.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    first_value = Double.valueOf(jtextfield.getText());
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                }
                jtextfield.setText("");
                operation[0] = "*";
            }
        });
        bt13.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    first_value = Double.valueOf(jtextfield.getText());
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                }
                jtextfield.setText("");
                operation[0] = "+";
            }
        });
        //Обрабатываем при нажатии на равно, считаем второе значение с текстового поля
        bt_res.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    result();
                } catch (DivisionByZero e1) {
                    //e1.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Calculator.this, "Деление на ноль запрещено!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    jtextfield.setText("");
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                }
            }
        });
        //запрещает ввод всех букв и символов с клавиатуры, кроме цифр
        jtextfield.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                super.keyPressed(e);
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(([0-9]){0,}([\\.]){0,})+$");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(jtextfield.getText());
                if (!m.matches()) {
                    jtextfield.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }//закрытие конструктора

    // Метод проверяет строку на содержание точки
    private boolean validinput(String input) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)(\\.{0,1})?$");
        return p.matcher(input).find();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Calculator();
    }

    //Проводит все вычисления для кнопки равно и перехватывает это исключение. Метод бросает исключение "Деление на ноль"
    void result() throws DivisionByZero {
        double second_value = Double.valueOf(jtextfield.getText());
        if ("+".equals(operation[0])) {
            jtextfield.setText((first_value + second_value) + "");
        } else if ("-".equals(operation[0])) {
            jtextfield.setText((first_value - second_value) + "");
        } else if ("/".equals(operation[0])) {
            if (second_value == 0) {
                throw new DivisionByZero();
            }
            jtextfield.setText((first_value / second_value) + "");
        } else if ("*".equals(operation[0])) {
            jtextfield.setText((first_value * second_value) + "");
        }
    }

    private class DivisionByZero extends Exception {
    }
}

    //JUnit test
public class CalculatorTest {

    @Test
    void result() {
        assertEquals(5, 2 + 3);
        assertEquals(6, 2 * 3);
        assertEquals(2, 5 - 3);
        assertEquals(2, 6 / 3);
        assertEquals(10.2, 6.2 + 4);
        assertEquals(-1, 7 - 8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы хотели проверить, как сама Java справляется с вычислениями, то да, правильно. Но *ваш* калькулятор вы ни на грамм не протестировали.

Comment: но, если так, то не получается 
assertEquals(4, new Calculator().result(2+2));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Первое.** Тест, который вы написали, тестирует только то, как сама JVM справляется с вычислениями.

**Второе.** Тест должен тестировать ваш класс `Calculator`. Однако если вы попробуете написать такой тест, у вас ничего не получится. Почему?

**Третье.** Юнит-тесты должны тестировать только логику приложения и не должны касаться ничего другого, например, UI, обращения к БД или веб-сервисам.

В чем проблема класса `Calculator`? В том, что в нем смешана логика математических расчетов и логика представления (UI). Вся математика у вас находится в методе `result()`. Для начала вам нужно убрать из него все, что связано с UI и оставить только математику. Например, как-нибудь так (*возможны ошибки компиляции, на Джаве уже давно не пишу*):

```
double result(double a, double b, string op) throws DivisionByZero {
    if ("+".equals(op)) {
        return a + b;
    } else if ("-".equals(op)) {
        return a - b;
    } else if ("/".equals(op)) {
        if (b == 0) {
            throw new DivisionByZero();
        }
        return a / b;
    } else if ("*".equals(op)) {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

Теперь, предварительно сделав этот метод публичным (а лучше вынеся его в класс `Calculator`, а нынешний класс переименовать в, например, `CalculatorFrame`), можно писать тесты, которые будут выглядеть примерно так:

```
@Test
void resultAddition() {
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    double res = calculator.result(2, 3, "+");
    assertEquals(5, res);
}

@Test
void resultMultiplication() {
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    double res = calculator.result(2, 3, "*");
    assertEquals(6, res);
}
```

Несколько советов насчет тестов:

1. Делайте один тест на один юзкейс (сложение, вычитание, умножение, деление и деление на ноль).
2. В каждом тесте можете проверять несколько вариантов данных (например, с нулем и отрицательными числами).